# Unable to import androidx.annotation.NonNull and all from androidx

Tags: android, android-studio, androidx

I created a project in Jan 2021, but after formatting my computer and reinstalling the latest version of Android Studio, now my project has an error, it cannot import all packages from androidx:

[image]

This are my dependencies from gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.primerappopencvtres"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        applicationId "opencv.org"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
implementation project(path: ':openCVLibrary320')
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.4'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.4'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
```

Gradle properties:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
# org.gradle.parallel=true
# AndroidX package structure to make it clearer which packages are bundled with the
# Android operating system, and which are packaged with your app"s APK
# https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/androidx-rn
android.useAndroidX=true
# Automatically convert third-party libraries to use AndroidX
android.enableJetifier=true
```

When I loaded this project to android studio, it asked  me to update the sdk path then a lot of updates were done. What could be the problem?. I did rebuild project, clean project, invalidate caches and restart and the problems keeps.

Comment: Can you rewrite the question in English.. there are some parts that seems like Spanish

Comment: Sorry bro. Now all is ok.

Comment: So, sometimes it's android studio bug, and you can normally run the app is that your case?

Comment: What??? really.. that's true.  I was capable of compile the app without problems.. I don't kwno what happens with android studio arctic fox. https://imgur.com/a/Xp2fB7P Thanks for the idea.

Comment: I had this before and after some time of android studio self-indexing project files, every thing was OK

Comment: I should migrate this proyecto to another or I should fix this, or wait for another android studio version...but if they don't fix this the next version the problem will not disappear.

Comment: Just wait for the next update and see before bothering of the migration